# Any advantage to isolate digital ground of an ADC from the rest of the top ground plane?

Tags: digital-logic, adc, ground-plane

What if you have the traces which run to a very sensitive sensor right next to the digital ground of an ADC, would it be an advantage at all to isolate the ground exit by cutting off the connection to the top plane, sending it straight to the ground plane through a large via and isolating it from everything else on the top plane? Could the HF ground current potentially affect the nearest measuring trace? Could any of the ground current get by the via and roam around on the top plane, or would 100% of it go straight down the via to the ground plane even if not isolated as in the image? Is the 0.5mm gap between the first signal trace and the upper ground plane wide enough to prevent any crosstalk from occurring if you have a 10MHz frequency on the digital ground? Would there be any disadvantage in doing it the way shown in the image?

[image]

Comment: What is your board stack up?  Usually you wouldn't have ground current on the top copper anyway (since it follows the power/signal traces), so the cut doesn't do anything.

Comment: I think the isolation could make it worse. Datasheets often encourage people to have an analog and digital ground which are only connected at one point. But I think this is difficult to do well in practice. This question has been asked and answered in many forms here before. If you search I am sure you can find lots of discussion about the merits of having analog and digital grounds that are separated. The key is to manage layout so that noisy aggressor signals are not routed near sensitive victim signals. That way, GND shouldn't have high noisy currents flowing on it.

Comment: *Read the ADC datasheet very thoroughly and carefully*, because 1) the datasheet from high-quality ADC vendors like Analog Devices and Linear Tech include example application circuits and layouts, and you can simply mimic their layout and get great results, and 2) there are often little surprises lurking in the datasheet. I recall one datasheet that had a footnote explaining that the AGND and DGND pins were *recommended to be connected to the same ground plane* -- the names were only intended to convey their connections to the circuitry inside the package, *not* their external connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is never a good idea to run a "sensitive" trace right into an ADC, if sensitive means that the trace has rather high impedance. ADC inputs in general cannot be treated as having a particularly high input impedance. If you want robust readings, buffer your signals into your ADC with a strong drive low impedance buffer.

That would also remove your headache about digital traces nearby your analog input traces. Do note that ADCs are mixed signal devices. There will always be digital signals nearby analog signals. If not on the PCB, then definitely inside the package.

Now about your ground proposal: Making that cut leaves a stub of the top layer plane nearby your signal traces. Stubs are antennas and those are especially good at crosstalking with other circuitry. Isolating any ground is usually bad idea. It forces return currents to take another path. All the HF digital return current that anyway wants to go to the GND via, will do that anyway and doesn't bother you. But all currents that want to go to the upper GND plane will have to take a detour. Either through another ground pin, creating a larger loop and more inductive coupling to sensitive nodes. Or through parasitic capacitances and through various pins altogether. So in general keep everything "ground" as firmly and tightly bonded together as possible.

If you worry about common-impedance coupling of the analog return current flowing through the ground plane, then use a dedicated return trace for the analog signal.

Comment: Thanks. The pins next to digital ground happen to be assigned to the sensor inputs for the ADC. I believe they can be multiplexed but I'm just leaving it as they designed it. The sensor is a PT100 RTD probe, they have anti-aliasing RC filters in front of the sensor in the design and IDK about adding a low impedance buffer but I’m just sticking with their exact design. For the stub, you mean the small stub coming from the GND pin with the via? I thought it had to be ¼ wavelength to radiate? My board has a lot of stitching vias throughout (not shown).

Comment: Is there a reason why some current would want to go down the via and some would want to go around it as you mentioned? I don’t fully understand how ground return current travels, I have never seen a good video on it. I’ve heard the theories on AC and DC return current but it’s not a full illustration. I'll probably just not use the isolation as it doesn't seem like it offers much benefit if any, and people would question the unconventional design regardless so it wouldn't be worth it IMO.

Comment: @wdbwdb1 every current going to the ADC from any periphery has an equal return current. HF return currents try to and should flow as close to their forward current as possible. this also minimizes EMI and Crosstalk. for some currents, that might mean the way through the via is good, for others, the way upwards. low frequency return currents will use all ground connections and could be channeled by a cut in GND if necessary. a better way to force LF currents along a path is a dedicated trace though while leaving the plane whole. I meant the stub on the top of the image. stitching vias are good.